# How to use forge to decrypt rsa-cipher with given private key in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, encryption, cryptography, forge

I trie to encrypt text in php and decrypt with javscript using RSA. In php i use `phpseclib`.
For the client-site i've tried `forge` by digitalbazaar.

According to the documentation, they create a private and a public key in one object and start the magic.

```
 /*** Generating 1024-bit key-pair */  
 keys = forge.pki.rsa.generateKeyPair(1024);  

 /*** public key encryption */    
 var ciphertext = keys.publicKey.encrypt("Secret");     

 /*** private key decryption */  
 var plaintext  = keys.privateKey.decrypt(ciphertext);
```

Is there a method to use a given private key as a string to decrypt messages in forge?

Comment: Please see this article: http://www.matasano.com/articles/javascript-cryptography/

Comment: I know this famous link.

Comment: Is there a reason why it doesn't apply in your case?

Answer (score 3):

You can convert PKCS#8 PEM encoded private keys (i.e. key strings staring with `-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----`)

```
var pem = readPEMKey(...); // read the string
var privKey = forge.pki.privateKeyFromPem(pem);
var pubKey = forge.pki.rsa.setPublicKey(privKey.n, privKey.e);

/*** public key encryption */    
var ciphertext = pubKey.encrypt("Secret");     
/*** private key decryption */  
var plaintext  = pkey.decrypt(ciphertext);
```

It is also possible (and a bit more complex) to create a private key from scratch with the key parameters:

```
var privKey = forge.pki.setPrivateKey(n, e, d, p, q, dP, dQ, qInv);
```

where :

- n: key modulus
- e: private exponent
- p: the first modulus prime factor
- q: the second modulus prime factor
- d: public exponent
- dP, dQ, qInv: the [chinese remainder theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_%28algorithm%29#Using_the_Chinese_remainder_algorithm) parameters

All these params are supposed to be `BigInteger` created with the `forge.util.createBuffer` function.